# Protractor/Jasmine - Calling done() after assertions on a list

Tags: angular, jasmine, protractor

I have written protractor tests with a format similar to below where I map an assertion over an list of elements (In this case an ElementArrayFinder).

```
        it("all dropdowns should be enabled", done => {
            ....

            elemArrayFinder.map((elem, idx) => {
                expect(elemArrayFinder.get(idx).isEnabled()).toBeTruthy();
                done();
            })
        });
```

My question is around the calling of done() - It appears this is called on the first assertion, instead of after all the assertions have been completed. Does this mean Jasmine/Protractor will move to the next test even though assertions continue to be made on the list of elements? Is there a way to call done() only when all assertions on the list items complete?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because `map` is a loop, given your code, `done()` *should* be called on the first loop. You should be able to just omit the `done()` and it should work. That said, to answer your question, you'd do something like this (though please *don't* do this :) ):

```
    it("all dropdowns should be enabled", done => {
        ....

        elemArrayFinder.map((elem, idx) => {
            expect(elemArrayFinder.get(idx).isEnabled()).toBeTruthy();
        }).then(done);
    });
```

Comment: But _don't_ do what I begrudgingly suggested... you don't need to call `done` when using Protractor. Also, thanks for the edit @alecxe :) I do love the protractor community here!

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I didn't realize protractor handled the async calls and calling done() wasn't required. That was causing some confusion for me when certain tests like this one were passing without it.